# Python Pipes do not receive outputs correctly

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

My code generally depends on two functions, one to process a large chunk of data over a number of iterations and one to generate a series of plots at the end of each iteration. In order to speed up the code, I'm attempting to use Python's multiprocessing capabilities in the form of Pools and Pipes so I can break up the large function into several sections then stitch the sections together and generate the plots with that output. However the `recv()` methods of my Pipes don't seem to actually work, and I'm stumped as to why.

```
def plots():

    #build axes and plots

    for i in range(num_sections):
        temp_arr = pipes_hist[i][0].recv()      #the KeyboardInterrupt traceback message points here
        arr_section += temp_arr       #in my actual code arr_section is predefined with the proper size

    #etc etc

def main_function(section_number):

     for m in range(num_iterations):
         #lots of code goes here

         pipes_hist[section_number][1].send(array_section)
         pipes_hist[section_number][1].close()

         #etc etc

#build list of pipes for each section

pipes_hist_send = [[] for i in range(num_sections)]
pipes_hist_recv = [[] for i in range(num_sections)]
pipes_hist = list(zip(pipes_hist_recv,pipes_hist_send))

for i in range(num_sections):
    pipes_hist[i] = list(pipes_hist[i])
    pipes_hist[i][0],pipes_hist[i][1] = Pipe()

#begin multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(num_sections)
    args = np.arange(num_sections)
    pool.map_async(main_function, args, chunksize=1)

    for m in range(num_iterations):
        plots()

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The code hangs at the `.recv()` method in `plots()`. I'm completely stumped and the documentation is pretty opaque in regards to what might be happening. Any and all help or insight would be appreciated

Comment: What platform are you running this on?  `multiprocessing` has some special code requirements under Windows, which you don't seem to be entirely fulfilling.  You're not going to get beyond one iteration in any case, because `main_function()` is closing its pipe inside the loop.

Comment: This is on Linux. Good point about the `pipe.close()` statement, what would you recommend I do with it in that case?

Comment: It might be easier if you just pass in a `queue` to the `main_function`, which is being run by multiple processes, and then just pull things off the queue to plot them. That way you don't need to manage so many individual `pipes`. The queues are muti-producer (and consumer).

Comment: I did try adding a JoinableQueue, but that hangs at the first queue.get() method as well, and in my actual code I would have multiple arrays being passed into the queue (not just `array_section` as in this code). Which makes me believe something must be wrong with my structure, but I have no idea what it could be